# Evaluate $1^{i+i}$

Tags: complex-numbers

I thought $1^{i+i}$ was equal to 1 but was told the answer was $e^{-4n \pi}$.

Why I was incorrect and what was used to find the correct answer?

Comment: To answer this well and correctly, answer us this first, do you know the difference between $\log$ and $\text{Log}$?  Have you heard of "branches" in the context of complex functions or so-called multi-valued functions?

Comment: I have heard of brach cuts but I do not know the difference between log and Log.

Comment: Log is the principal logarithm, and you compute that and add the rest of the "repeating" values (in a very rough sense) to get the rest. By the way Welcome to math stack exchange!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reckon that expressions like $z^w$, where $z$ and $w$ are complex numbers,
are best avoided. But, it you really, really must use it, then the natural interpretation
of $z^w$ is as
$$z^w=\exp(w\ln z).$$
Of course the catch here is that $\ln z$ is "many-valued", that is if $u$
is a logarithm of $z$ then so is $u+2n\pi i$ where $n$ is your favourite integer.
If you were being perverse, you might argue that $\ln 1$ should be $2\pi i$
rather than $0$ and so
$$1^{1+i}=\exp((1+i)(2\pi i))=\exp(2\pi i-2\pi)=e^{-2\pi}$$
etc.

Answer (score 0):

Because the complex power function is a multivalued function.

$1^{2i}=\exp(2i\cdot \mathrm{Ln}(1))=\exp(2i\cdot(\ln(1)+2n\pi i))=\exp(-4n\pi)$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that  $$1=e^{2k \pi i}$$

thus $$1^{2i} = (e^{2k\pi i})^{2i} = e^{-4k \pi}$$

Comment: Probably a dumb question but is it just n=n(e^(2k(pi)i))?

Comment: Yes it is true you just multiply by n

Answer (score 0):

$1^{i+i}$ needs to be evaluated from the perspective of complex analysis.

First note, that any complex number (which includes pure real and pure imaginary ones) can be presented as

$$z = r e^{i \theta}$$

Now, recall that $2i$ in polar form will be $2i = 2 e^{i \pi/2}$, because this number makes a $\pi/2$ angle with $x$-axis and has a length of $r = 2$ (it is just the absolute value of $2i$). So, now you have

$$1^{2i}=1^{2e^{i \pi/2}}= e^{2 i \log (1)} =e^{2 i(\mathrm{Log} (1)+2 i \pi n)} =e^{2 i(0+2 i \pi n)} =e^{-4 \pi n}$$